# git diff showing only lines that had a particular word added

Tags: git, diff

I know of a commit in which a problematic change was introduced. However, the commit is so large that it's breaking gitlab, and I currently don't have a good tool for searching for a particular difference in the large commit.

Searching in git for a *commit* that introduces or removes a word is very simple, however, I already know the commit, and need to know instead which exact *files/lines* were affected. How can I do that?

Let's assume that the commit is sha `abcdef1` and is the immediate ancestor of the current branch/HEAD. I'd like to search for the string `word` in the diff between this commit and the one before it.

Comment: Are you looking for `git show`?

Comment: I figured out that this gets partway there: `git diff abcdef1^ abcdef1 -Sword --diff-filter-M` but doesn't show just the changed lines. That's actually okay for my purposes, but someone else may want to see the answer to the question as asked.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approximation is `git --color <log/diff/etc> -S <word> | ack --nocolor $'(^(?!\e\\[31m|\e\\[32m)|<word>)'` which will use color marker matching to  only show change lines containing the word (but will still show change headers). It's nice for filtering huge change blocks, not so nice when you have lots of changed files / blocks and most of them don't contain the word as the headers will still show up for those. You could use something more powerful than ack/grep such as awk to remember the last yellow block (commit id), white block (file header) and cyan block (change block header) and only show them when the word is found in a red/green line, but it would be a bit more complicated.